# PHP GTK button click

Tags: php, image, button, gtk, gtk2

I'm trying to make this **button change background**  ***when***  **you click it** and this is what I have:

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('gtk')) {
    die("Please load the php-gtk2 module in your php.ini\r\n");
}
function loc(){
  return dirname(__FILE__);
};
$wnd = new GtkWindow();
$wnd->set_title('Picture Viewer');
$wnd->set_resizable(false);
$wnd->set_position(GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
$wnd->connect_simple('destroy', array('gtk', 'main_quit'));



$im = GtkImage::new_from_file(loc()."\bg.jpg");
$btn = new GtkButton;
$btn->set_image($im);

$btn->clicked(function(){
  $im = GtkImage::new_from_file(loc()."\bg2.jpg");
  $btn->set_image($im);
});

$wnd->add($btn);

$wnd->show_all();
Gtk::main();
?>
```

**Why doesn't this work?**

I think **that the** `$btn->clicked(function(){` **part** is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$btn->clicked` actually *emits* the clicked signal.  What you want to do is *connect* a function to the signal:

```
$btn->connect('clicked', 'change_background');

function change_background($whichbutton)
{
    $im = GtkImage::new_from_file(loc()."\bg2.jpg");
    $whichbutton->set_image($im);
}
```